# Android Show/Hide Tabwidget On button Click

Tags: android, button, tabactivity, tabwidget

Hey can we hide/show tab layout on button click which will be placed below the tab widget it self.

Eg :

[image]

When i try to hide - setVisible(View.GONE) the tabwidget whole screens goes black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to me would just use the android menu as the way to choose between different tabs instead of a real tab view. When the user clicks on a menu button, you load another activity and the menu gets hidden again.

The tabhost is meant to stay there throughout the entire app lifecycle. Using it like this would be wrong. A way to achieve this using the tab would be to set it completely invisible and then load the activity that normally is in the tab on the whole screen.

Comment: I tried making it using slideing widget with flags set to no_animation and no_history but my application is based on web services and xml parsing so on every click(buttons) whole activity is being called again and whole parsing is done. So i preferred tab widget since activity state is maintained.